# Deleting a commit in Between other commits

Tags: git, github

I have a local and its corresponding github repo. I have some commits as

```
A <- B <- C <- D
```

A being the latest.

This is situation on both the repos. I want to delete commit C as if it never happened.

So it should be like on `git log`

```
A <- B <- D
```

on both repos.

I tried `git reset --soft <sha-commit-C>` and am now stuck. I can not see `A, B`. Before doing any further steps i want to be fully sure that i know what i am doing.

`git reflog` gives me :

```
git reflog
73ea54d HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 73ea54d8
a594699 HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/unique_ptr_release
a594699 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from unique_ptr_release to a594699fb6f7d85bc8
a594699 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from unique_ptr_release to unique_ptr_release
a594699 HEAD@{4}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'master' into unique_ptr_release
```

`HEAD@{4}` is what my Head was before `reset --soft` command.

How do i get out of this situation ?

Comment: copy/backup your `.git` folder before doing further experiments.

Comment: thanks. just did that.

Comment: you probaly can cherry-pick the missing commits (use the sha's from the reflog) into your current branch and leave out c to get the desired result.

Comment: git reset --hard a594699 brought me back to ABCD :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Git-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is what are you looking for.

in your case of commit `A-B-C-D`, and want to remove C, try:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

it will show the last 3 of your commits via editor (mine is vim),
just delete (in vim: `dd`) the line of commit you want to remove,
then save it (in vim: `:wq`).

Done, view the `git log` and you will see that the `C` commit is removed.

*don't forget to backup your code or .git folder.

Comment: is my HEAD is at A ? git log shows C <- D. i have done git reset --soft C. SHould i just do git rebase -i HEAD-3 ?

Comment: Since i have already pushed: i do not know much about git but should i use git revert ?

Comment: It is already in my question: HEAD@{4} commit(merge) is my A.

Comment: oh,sorry. you should go back to `A`, use `git reset --soft HEAD@{4}` .after that do the `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Comment: It does not allow me saying that their is already a rebase-merge directory.

Comment: you can use `git rebase --abort` to abort previous rebase.

Comment: is it option to remove  from git  repostory website ?  not locally

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you back up your .git folder.
2. Ensure commit D , don’t rely upon the changes made in C.
3. git rebase --onto D B~1 (as A is the latest commit)

Comment: D does not depend upon C. Should i just type in git rebase --onto B D~1 . B and D means their SHAs ? I hope you understand that my current situation is that of after git reset --soft C

Comment: I have just edited my answer, pl check.  Yes, B and D means their SHAs.

Comment: git log shows C D. I can not find SHA of B. How to find that ?

Comment: with git reset --soft C, if you do git status, it shows A and B as new files, please commit B and commit A with proper commit message.  Now you are back to original.  Then issue git rebase as mentioned above.

Comment: A and B are not files but my commits. As they are on the server. If i commit it would become commit 'F'. Can't i fetch these commits from the server ? Is reset --soft is also so dangerous. I read somewhere that doing git reset --hard a594699 <- where a594699 is in the output of git reflog. Should i do that ?