# How to create branch from several commits back?

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to git.

Currently I have the commits depicted below, which have been pushed to remote. 
[image: only 1 branch]

I created a branch (branch1) when I had to start building a ui.
But I realized that I should have made a second branch when I worked on another feature (in green).

How do I get from my current setup to the following setup? If it makes things easier, I'm working on with no other collaborators.

[image: separate branches]

Update:
All the answers worked, I accepted the first one that was submitted, but used a combination of the answers. To undo commits , we can use the interactive rebase tool ([Deleting a commit in Between other commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655170/deleting-a-commit-in-between-other-commits)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Don't cherry-pick. Use git-rebase.**

Here's where you are right now:

[image]

**1) Create a new branch at the head of `branch1`:**

```
git branch branch2
```

[image]

**2) Reset `branch1` to where its head should be:**

You can use either `git log` to find the hash of the last good commit, or (in the case of my example) use `HEAD~2` to go back two commits.

```
git reset --hard <back-there>
```

[image]

**3) Switch to `branch2`**

```
git checkout branch2
```

[image]

**4) Rebase everything *from* `branch1` *up to* `branch2` onto `master`**

```
git rebase --onto master branch1
```

[image]

Comment: As a side note, `git rebase` is essentially automating however many `git cherry-pick` commands are required to get the job done.  So "don't cherry-pick, rebase instead" means "don't hand-pick, use the power-tool picker". :-)

Comment: Even though I have a competing answer, I can say indefinitely... This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty awesome, actually!

First off, find the commit hash you want to create the branch from using `git log`. Copy the sha hash of the new branch.

Run the following (with replacing the sha hash with your actual sha):

```
git checkout 051ab99e1bb7359d7136d621d9feacfc82aa8721
git checkout -b my-new-branch
git push --set-upstream origin my-new-branch #optional, only if you want to push it to remote
```

After that, you can use `git cherry-pick` to add the green commits like so:

```
git cherry-pick SHA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git checkout master              # go to master branch
$ git checkout -b branch2          # create & checkout branch2

$ git reflog                       # copy commit hash of your two green commits
$ git cherry-pick <commit-hash-1>  # pick frist green commit
$ git cherry-pick <commit-hash-2>  # pick second green commit
```

Your branch2 is ready. Now you should undo the last two commits of branch1
    
`$ git checkout branch1             # go to branch1 
$ git reset --hard HEAD~2          # undo last two commits`